# Layout content overlap in Oreo

Tags: android, android-layout, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I've two child layouts in `ConstraintLayout` (One above the other). It's showing second layout above first in all Android versions except Android 8.1 (Android O),where the second layout is hidden behind the first layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/subscriberViewContainer"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/publisherViewContainer"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Are there any changes that need to be done in Android O to get the same response as the rest?

[image: Ideal case]
[image: Android O]

Comment: Try manually specifying an elevation via `android:elevation`, rather than relying upon default behaviors. It's odd that `ConstraintLayout` is behaving differently, though, since that's from a library, not the framework.

Comment: @CommonsWare I found the last layout to which i'm adding view is coming on top, which is very odd. So i put a temporary fix , if the build version > 25 then add view to second layout again .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the last layout to which i'm adding view is coming on top, which is very odd. So i put a temporary fix , if the build version > 25 then add view to second layout again .It's very weird but at the end of the day , i had to fix it.

Comment: i was also having same issue, i was getting this because of **app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"** parameter of the last element in ConstraintLayout. And i was also setting all four constraints to this last element. After removing **app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent** it works perfectly in all the devices. This overlapping is only happening in Oreo devices only